# How to stop looping on success

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, foreach, kendo-grid

I have a script which loops through my kendo-grid when an article-id is submitted, this script adds +1 to the quantity when a match is found. After a match is found I want my script to stop looping since the same article-id can have more than 1 row in the grid and the idea is to only add +1 to the first match. I know that a foreach loop can't contain a `break;` and using a for-loop doesn't seem to work for the kendo-grid datarows. Currently the code adds +1 to every matching row. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

JS:

```
$('#txtBarcode').submit(function (e) {
    var grid = $("#GCLinesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = $("#GCLinesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var allData = grid.dataSource.data();
    var code = this.value;

    $.each(allData, function (index, item) {
        if (item.ArticleCode == code) {
            if (item.CollectedQuantity < item.Quantity) {
                item.CollectedQuantity++;                    
                item.dirty = true;
                dataSource.sync();   
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Don't use jQuery `each`, just do a plain `for` loop and exit when you need to.

Comment: you can abort a jQuery `each` by returning `false`. Or you use [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the proper item: `var item = allData.find(item => item.ArticleCode === code && item.CollectedQuantity < item.Quantity);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `return false;` once the match has been found should do the trick.

Comment: awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Use `return false` is official way to break out of [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loops early.

Comment: This is a feature of jQuerys `each()` loop and doesn't apply for the native Array methods. Just to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function and return when if is true:

```
$('#txtBarcode').submit(function (e) {
    var grid = $("#GCLinesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataSource = $("#GCLinesGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var allData = grid.dataSource.data();
    var code = this.value;
    loop(/*args here*/)
})

function loop (/*args you need here*/) {
   $.each(allData, function (item, index) {/*fix forEach*/
      if (item.ArticleCode == code) {
         if (item.CollectedQuantity < item.Quantity) {
            item.CollectedQuantity++;                     
            item.dirty = true;
            dataSource.sync();
            return false; /*or return some value you need*/
         }
      }
   })
}
```